# Ruby custom include? for set

Tags: ruby, hash, set, comparator

I defined a class called Point as follows:

```
class Point
  def initialize (x,y)
    @x, @y = x, y
  end

  attr_accessor :x, :y
end
```

In another part of my project, I generate random Point objects and put them into a set. The points in the set however need to be unique:

```
(1..numObstacles).each do |n|
    p = Point.new(rand(minX..maxX), rand(minY..maxY))
      if !@obstacles.include?(p)
        @obstacles.add(p)
    end
end
```

I know this does not work for the uniqueness constraint since in every iteration of the loop, p is a different object, and Ruby does not know how to compare two point objects. But I cannot come up with / find a proper way to override the include? method or provide a custom comparator (like in Java).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple solution: make your Point a one liner:

```
Point = Struct.new :x, :y
```

All necessary methods (#hash, #eql?) are then defined automatically.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation for `Set`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html):

> Set uses Hash as storage, so you must note the following points:
>
> - Equality of elements is determined according to Object#eql? and Object#hash.
> - Set assumes that the identity of each element does not change while it is stored. Modifying an element of a set will render the set to an unreliable state.
> - When a string is to be stored, a frozen copy of the string is stored instead unless the original string is already frozen.

So you need to override and implement the `eql?` and `hash` methods on the `Point` class.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you need to use a hack kind of thing by maintaining a variable and then iterating the set.

```
(1..numObstacles).each do |n|
    p, cntr = Point.new(rand(minX..maxX), rand(minY..maxY)), false
    @obstacles.each { |po| cntr = true if po.x == p.x && po.y == p.y }
    @obstacles.add(p) unless cntr
    end
end
```

What we are doing is iterating through the set and then setting the `cntr` to true, if we find a duplicate, which we then use to add to `@obstacles`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how do you want to achieve a goal. You might either override `eql?` and `hash` on your `Point` (as suggested by @TomDalling) or you might override the `include?` on `@obstacles` eigenclass:

```
class << @obstacles 
   def include? other
     Point === other && self.any? { |p| 
      other.x == p.x && other.y == p.y 
     }   
   end 
end
```

The former approach is better whether you want to deal with `Point`s only. The latter is more customizable, since you may then check for totally different objects.

Please note, that whether you expect `Point`s to change their values during lifecycle, the latter approach should be used (according to “Set assumes that the identity of each element does not change while it is stored.”)

Answer (score 0):

```
(1..numObstacles).each do |n|
    p = Point.new(rand(minX..maxX), rand(minY..maxY))
      @obstacles << p
      @obstacles.uniq!
    end
end

or if you need the number of things in the array to be a certain amount:

until @obstacles.length == numObstacles do |n|
    p = Point.new(rand(minX..maxX), rand(minY..maxY))
     @obstacles << p
     @obstacles.uniq!
    end
end
```

Also numObstacles should be num_obstacles.  I like this way because it is declarative.  6/10 programmers see a struct and go "Awww man!!"  This is not a one liner but